# when i press the button program freezes

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

hi i made a notepad to read texts but when i press the button read the program freezes and start read and after it finish program work again

i need to be able to press button read and if i want to stop reading i press button stop [image]

```
def read_file():
    content = textPad.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
    speak (content)
def clear():
    textPad.configure(state="normal")
    textPad.delete(0,END);
def open_command():
    file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=top,mode='rb',title='Select a file')
    if file != None:
        content = file.read()
        textPad.configure(state="normal")
        textPad.insert('1.0',content)
        textPad.configure(state="disabled")
        file.close()
        return content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single threaded programs can only do one thing at a time. If `speak(content)` takes a long time, you won't be able to interact with your GUI until it is finished.

You must run the `speak(content)` command either in another thread or another process if you need to be able to interrupt it.

Comment: you mean run command in other thread and terminate it when i need to stop that is the only way